# docview in emacs: refreshing dvi content automatically

Tags: emacs, latex, docview

Is there a way Emacs can automatically refresh the buffer showing the dvi right after my LaTeX compilation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use interactive function:

```
auto-revert-mode
```

to enable reloading when the file changes.

Comment: Or put 
(global-auto-revert-mode t) in .emacs in case you want this behavior for all files(I most certainly do)

Answer (score 22):

The global auto revert is not always desirable, in fact I only use it for for the DocView to see the new output of pdflatex.

The following will allow auto revert for the DocView major mode

```
(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)
```

Comment: +1, this automation is exactly what I wanted and makes sense for read-only doc-view mode buffers, but would be potentially dangerous for other buffers.